# Can't create a timer that runs a function in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xna

this time I come to you guys asking for help with Timers (System.Timers to be specific, I believe)

I need to make a timer that runs a function every second, so far this is what I've got:

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
 {
     Timer CooldownTracker;

     protected override void LoadContent()
     {
        CooldownTracker = new Timer();
        CooldownTracker.Interval = 1000;
        CooldownTracker.Start();
     }

     private void DecreaseCooldown(List<Brick> bricks)
     {
         foreach (Brick brick in bricks)
         {
            if (brick.Cooldown == 0)
                brick.Cooldown = 2;
            else
               brick.Cooldown--;
         }
     }
 }
```

...How do I make the timer run the DecreasedCooldown(List bricks) function? I've tried with Timer.Elapsed but I get nothing, I can't pass down the arguments that way. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a timer in XNA. The preferred method is to work out of the `Update()` method. Basically you have a class-level field/property that contains the time until the method should be triggered, let's call it `timeLeft`. Every time `Update()` is called, subtract the elapsed time (using the gameTime argument) from `timeLeft`. Once `timeLeft` <= 0, call the method to trigger and reset `timeLeft`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a [Timer Elapsed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
CooldownTracker = new Timer();
CooldownTracker.Elapsed += CooldownTracker_Elapsed; //HERE
CooldownTracker.Interval = 1000;
CooldownTracker.Start();
```

and then the event:

```
void CooldownTracker_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DecreaseCooldown(yourList);
}
```

Comment: I can see that, but how can I send the list to the DecreaseCooldown function if it's inside CooldownTracker_Elapsed ?

Comment: @krieg, like `DecreaseCooldown(yourList);`, replace `yourList` with the name of your variable.

Comment: You could try using System.Threading.Timer and pass in the list as the state.

Comment: @krieg, I am not sure how you have defined that list in your code, can you update your question with how you have defined that list and how you are passing it to the method `DecreaseCooldown`

Comment: Oh hang on, I just got it, it was another function that I forgot to delete that was creating issues. I'm sorry! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread if you want. It's not so accurate maybe cause of ThreadPool but can help.
Like

```
private bool run = true;



Thread timer = new Thread(Run);
timer.Start();
```

And define Run

```
private void Run()
{
     while(run)
     {
         // Call function
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Time in millis
     }
}
```

if you get cross-thread exception try to use for loop instead of foreach or lock your resources.